# How do I install the balloontip module for python in mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, balloon-tip

How can I install the balloontip module for python? I am trying to write code where python checks which os system the code is being run on and then notifies the user about something. I have to write a different type of code for mac and a different one for windows. I want to install this module in my mac so I can write the windows part of the notify code. How can I do this? Here is a link to the module I am talking about:
https://gist.github.com/BoppreH/4000505

Comment: You can just save it as balloontip.py in your working directory, then in your main file: `import balloontip` or `import balloontip as bt`.

Comment: @BenQuigley but what happens when i need to send my code to someone else

Comment: willl they be able to run it

Comment: They will if you add that file to the same repository that your main file is in (e.g. commit it also to your github repo) so that anyone who downloads that repo also downloads this script. (You can give credit & thanks to boppreh for that code snippet in the Readme.)

Comment: You can also always just paste all the functions from the gist into your main file, if you really want there to be just one file.

Comment: @BenQuigley Okay thanks very much